# Why my css style cannot load my image url on Chrome

Tags: css

My web cannot load with my url image, but when I change other url, its work

[This capture when I use my url image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUiGZ.png)

```
.colored {
        background-color: #0000;
        mask: url("https://get-married.site/uploads/ornamen/24.png") no-repeat center / contain;
        -webkit-mask: url("https://get-married.site/uploads/ornamen/24.png") no-repeat center / contain;
    }
```

But its work when I use this url

[This when I use other URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZvTh.png)

```
https://i.ibb.co/FhZb3Xs/CJcLK.png
```

Comment: Do you get an error message in your console?

Comment: No any error message, but when Inspect element on browser, the url not show the image preview, *My capture on my question

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually do get an error, my friend. When looking into the console, you will get the following error message:

> index.html:1 Access to image at 'https://get-married.site/uploads/ornamen/24.png' from origin 'https://cdpn.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This means that you are not allowed to use this image in your code because it has some protection. As long as you are not the owner of the page where the image is located, you will not be able to use the image.

Comment: Sorry, i am not notice that, any suggest for fix it ?

Comment: You can't really fix it. You are not the owner of the image. Therefore you are also not allowed to download the image to your server and use it locally. Im afraid you will have to find another image.